# Showing a text on the picture taken from Camera and saving it in Gallery

Tags: android

I want to add a text on the picture taken from device camera. So I am launching my activity once Camera intent action is fired. My question is how to show a text on the picture and once user clicks on save button the picture will be saved in device's gallery with the text.Please give some idea.

Thanks

Comment: use an imageview to display the picture!

Answer (score 1):

Following Snippet will give you some pointers

Here come your logic.

Here i am loading png file from drawable resource.You need to fetch it from directory.

If you want to make it more attractive Use Custom fonts by saving them in Assets/fonts

Don't directly hard-code Text you want to put rather load it from somewhere.

Use some different color.

I have manually set the Text Size .You should put some logic (Dont hard-code it)

In drawText i have harddoded Text height as 30.You should apply some logic to get Text Height.

Finally You have Background Bitmap save it.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setTextSize(50);
paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

canvas.drawText("Hello Image", (background.getWidth() - paint.measureText("Hello Image")) / 2, background.getHeight() - 30, paint);

imageView.setImageBitmap(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this post really helps you [Link is here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity).

You should make use of FrameLayout and then add your imageView to it in this post given example how to set image just add textview with background transparent after it , FrameLayout displays it upon image and you can also position it(just write your textview in RelativeLayout )

Hope this explanation works for you...

Comment: Hi, My problem was how to launch an Activity when my camera is opened. Is it anyway possible?Which intent action is fired when device's Camera is on? I was unable to receive that particular intent action(if any) using BroadCastReceiver.
Please help me in that.